# Random Recursive AVL tree height error

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I've been working on this program for several days now and have gotten it to mostly work. However, there is a random read access error when calling the recursive height function. I've been stuck for several hours now trying to fix this bug, I've stepped through the function too many times to count, and can't seem to find a pattern to the error. I've attempted to fix this by checking for null, but since the node I'm checking doesn't even equal null, this fails as well. The most confounding part of this error is that it is completely random. It probably is a simple fix that I just can't see. Any help would be awesome.

Here is the code

```
int Tree::height(Node* p)
{
int left, right;


//if node is null return 0
if (p == nullptr || p == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is where I attempt to see if the node has invalid values. However this works only sometimes, as there are times where the node has no value at all.

```
//if node has invalid values, return 0
if (p->getTheData() == NULL || p->getTheData() >= 1000000000 || p-    >getTheData() <= -1000000000)
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is where the nonexistent node is being passed in when recursively checking the tree. I don't know how or why this happens

```
//recursively add to the height to check the balance
left = height(p->getLLink());
right = height(p->getRLink());

if (left > right)
    return left + 1;
else
    return right + 1;
}
```

This function initially is what balances the tree. I pass in the node and if needed it then balances the tree.

```
void Tree::balFactor(Node* p, int inNodeData)
{
//declare needed objects and variables
int unBalancedRight = -2;
int two = 2;
Node* rightLink;
Node* leftLink;

//check to see if node is null and set a catch case
if (p == NULL || p->getRLink() == NULL)
{
    rightLink = new Node;
    rightLink->setBalFac(1001);
}
//if node is valid, move right
else
{
    rightLink = p->getRLink();
}

if (p == NULL || p->getLLink() == NULL)
{
    leftLink = new Node;
    leftLink->setBalFac(1001);
}

//if node is valid move
else
{
    leftLink = p->getLLink();
}

//check to see if the node is valid
if (p != nullptr)
{
    //check to see if the passed in node number is greater than the passed in data
    if (inNodeData > p->getTheData())
    {
        //check to see if the tree needs to be balanced
        if ((height(rightLink) - height(leftLink) == two))
        {
            //check to see what type of balancing needs to happen
            if (inNodeData > p->getRLink()->getTheData())
                rotateRightOnce(p);
            else
                rotateRightTwice(p);
        }
    }
    //check to see in incoming data is less than p node
    else if (inNodeData < p->getTheData())
    {
        //check to see if the data needs to be balanced
        if ((height(p->getLLink() - height(p->getRLink())) == two))
        {
            //check to see what type of rotation needs to happen
            if (inNodeData < p->getLLink()->getTheData())
                rotateLeftOnce(p);
            else
                rotateLeftTwice(p);
        }
    }

    //check the balance factor recursively until all nodes have been checked
    balFactor(p->getLLink(), inNodeData);
    balFactor(p->getRLink(), inNodeData);
}
}
```

Let me know if you need any other details

Comment: Please don't edit your code to fix the error, it makes your question less useful for anyone else. Also note you still have the same issue with the other if statement which calls height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to step through it in a debugger. Then you can inspect the tree at each point and see where it is going wrong.

Here are a few things to look at:

You make `leftLink` and `rightLink` using `new Node`, but never free them. Note that you don't always want to free them as they sometime point to valid nodes. You might want to rethink how this is working.

More importantly, this line:

```
if ((height(rightLink - height(leftLink)) == two))
```

is calling height after subtracting another height from a pointer, as you have your brackets mixed up. I think you meant

```
if ((height(rightLink) - height(leftLink)) == two)
```

That could cause serious problems.

(Edited for clarity)

Comment: The problem seems to always happen at the line where I check to see if the node I've passed to height contains valid data. I don't understand why a invalid node is being passed through. Because the error is random, as in it occurs at any point during the building of the tree, it's been hard to find when or even how it occurs.

Comment: That line I highlighted will pass an invalid pointer, which will cause that problem. If `height(leftLink)` is 10, you are then calling `height(rightLink-10)`. `rightLink - 10` is unlikely to be a valid pointer.

Comment: It worked! At first it didn't seem to, but then I noticed I had done the exact same thing at a different point in my code. Fixed both and seems to run fine now. Thanks!